# Squid Proxy Problem to arised after update

Tags: proxy, squid, restart

When I restart squid web proxy service, I receive the following errors. What are these errors?

```
/etc/init.d/squid restart

Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service squid restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the restart(8) utility, e.g. restart squid
restart: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.64" (uid=1000 pid=2979 comm="restart) interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Restart" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init"))
```

Has anybody else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1):

execute

> service squid restart

as said in the message:

> Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
>   Upstart job, you may also use the restart(8) utility, e.g. restart squid

It's more easy to remember in fact :-P

Comment: +1 right ... not an error just a friendly notice

Comment: As you said,I was restarted the service.But,I am receiving same error.

Comment: Did you execute using sudo ?

Comment: yes, I execute using sudo.